# GROUP BY Month Number and Year

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have a query that produces a Month Number and a Year.  I want to sort the results by the Month Number and Year.  So, Month Num 1, Year 2012 is first and then 2, 2012 so on and so forth.  How can I do this?

```
SELECT
    a.Vendor,
    vn.ACNAME,
    a.FiscalMonthNum,
    a.FiscalYear,
    a.ModDate,
    a.QtySold,
    a.ExtCost
FROM
    dbo.S2K_VEND vn
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT
    sd.IFPRVN AS Vendor,
    fc.FiscalMonthNum,
    fc.FiscalYear,
    sd.Mod_Date As ModDate,
    SUM(sd.SBQSHP) AS QtySold,
    SUM(sd.SBEPRC) AS ExtCost
FROM
    dbo.SalesData sd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FiscalCalendar fc ON fc.FiscalDate = sd.SBINDT
GROUP BY
    sd.IFPRVN,
    fc.FiscalMonthNum,
    fc.FiscalYear,
    sd.Mod_Date
)a
ON vn.ACVEND = a.Vendor
ORDER BY
    a.FiscalMonthNum
```

Comment: use [order by](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx#BasicSyntax) like  ORDER BY [Month Number], Year

Comment: I agree with Srikanth, You could use:
ORDER BY Month,Year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say something like:

```
order by FiscalMonthNum asc , -- Major order. Use 'asc' if you want it in ascending sequence (or simply omit it as that is the default)
         FiscalYear desc -- Minor order. Use 'desc' if you want it in descending sequence
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT
    a.Vendor,
    vn.ACNAME,
    a.FiscalMonthNum,
    a.FiscalYear,
    a.ModDate,
    a.QtySold,
    a.ExtCost
FROM
    dbo.S2K_VEND vn
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT
    sd.IFPRVN AS Vendor,
    fc.FiscalMonthNum,
    fc.FiscalYear,
    sd.Mod_Date As ModDate,
    SUM(sd.SBQSHP) AS QtySold,
    SUM(sd.SBEPRC) AS ExtCost
FROM
    dbo.SalesData sd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FiscalCalendar fc ON fc.FiscalDate = sd.SBINDT
GROUP BY
    sd.IFPRVN,
    fc.FiscalMonthNum,
    fc.FiscalYear,
    sd.Mod_Date
)a
ON vn.ACVEND = a.Vendor
ORDER BY
    a.FiscalMonthNum, a.FiscalYear
```